# How to create a single global char* in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, global-variables, c++98

I am maintaining a custom logging system that uses macros to do things like append a timestamp and source file name to each message.  So something like:

```
AI_LOG("Hello %s", "World!");
```

might result in:

```
(16.38) HelloWorld.cpp LOG: Hello World!
```

Currently, it creates a char* buffer on the stack, places the initial part of the output into the beginning of the buffer, and then uses snprintf to copy the output into the remainder of the buffer.  This all works... except that it creates the buffer on the stack, and if I have a deep enough stack with enough log statements and I don't keep the buffer quite small (e.g. 256 characters), I can get stack overflows.  I now have a need to output much longer strings, so putting all those buffers on the stack isn't going to work for me anymore.

With that background in mind... I'd like to move to a single global char array, which I will make quite big (probably something like 4K characters to start).  However, my understanding is that if I just say something like:

```
#define AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 4092
char AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER[AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

in my output system's .h file, then I run the risk of having a separate buffer being created by every file that includes that .h file.  Is that a real problem?  If so, is there a good (compiler-agnostic, C++98 compliant, non-Boost-using) way to get the single buffer that I want?

I was leaning toward doing this in the header:

```
#define AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 4096
class AIOutputBuffer
{
public:
    static char buffer[AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
};
```

And then in the .cpp I can:

```
char GAIA::AIOutputBuffer::buffer[AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

But that's giving me linker headaches... Maybe I'm not quite doing it right yet?

And before people suggest it... yes, I could probably rewrite it to use strings or streams... but I don't really want to rewrite the whole system, nor do I have the time and resources to do that.  This system works well and gives me a lot of flexibility - I just need to handle the memory usage problem.

Comment: Why don't you just use some kind of macro that invokes cout or similar, without a buffer?

Comment: Why use a macro at all? If the compiler won't inline your logging functions odds are pretty good that putting the code inline is a bad idea.

Comment: @user4581301 You won't have access to line or file information if you are using a function.

Comment: @KevinDill, If you use c++, why not use std::string?

Comment: In last paragraph he wrote that he doesn't want to use strings or streams

Comment: @PcAF But the why isn't answered. If he's already doing this behind a macro, it wouldn't change the external interface. There is no "rewrite the whole system" because the debugging system seems like a bad idea and it would not change the surroundings. It would just eliminate the C-style cruft.

Comment: Use an `extern` declaration in the header and define it in one of your source files.

Comment: @WilliamKappler: "*You won't have access to line or file information if you are using a function.*" You can created a function taking the line and file macros as arguments.

Comment: Understand where he's going with with this and can understand not wanting to pass the line etc into the function. Cleaner to write, but no faster to run. Keep it simple and debugging shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I don't want to switch to using cout because (a) the system is fairly complex (and works), (b) I don't understand the tradeoffs well enough (when I'm working in a buffer that I create, I know exactly what it does in memory), and (c) I don't have time or money to do a major rewrite.

For the same reasons, I don't want to switch to std::string.

In any case, neither of those would solve my problem - which is that I need to globally allocate the workspace, whether that workspace is a char*, a string, or a stream.

Comment: "*Currently, it creates a `char*` buffer on the stack [..] if I have a deep enough stack with enough log statements and I don't keep the buffer quite small (e.g. 256 characters), I can get stack overflows.*" What about declaring the buffer `static`?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments (thanks Dmitri!) I used extern, and it worked like a charm.  So in the header:

```
#define AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 256
extern char AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER[AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

then in the .cpp:

```
char AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER[AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Comment: Warning: If you have multiple threads running in the client code it will be very easy to have two messages hit the buffer at the same time and destroy each other.

Comment: Yeah, so far I'm single threaded.  If that ever changes... this will be one of many worries. :)

Answer (score 0):

While you solved your problem, there's a nicer solution that relies on `std::string` for memory management. Also, it works perfectly well in a multithreaded environment.

The idea is to use the oldschool `snprintf` but let `std::string` take care of memory management:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>

std::string va(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    // make sure your stack can handle a one-time allocation of a buffer of this size
    const auto BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;   

    // ...unless you know you're not going to call this from multiple threads; 
    // then you can make this buffer static and the size can be increased
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    std::vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    buffer[sizeof(buffer) - 1] = '\0';

    return buffer;
}
```

Usage: nothing unusual here: `auto logMsg = va("Hello %s", "World!");`.

Comment: @deviantfan Well, the return value of the function is (of type) `std::string`.

Comment: Uh ... sorry, I didn't see that :D

Comment: OP is apparently trying to avoid stack allocations (see question) - presumably he is on a memory-constrained embedded system or some such - allocating an 8 kb temporary buffer on the stack is probably not the way to go, given that: *"[if] I don't keep the buffer quite small (e.g. 256 characters), I can get stack overflows"*.

Comment: @PaulR OP explicitly mentioned that the problem stems from calling this function many times and allocating a lot of buffers (_if I have a deep enough stack with enough log statements_); here we only need to allocate it once and it's destroyed when the function returns. `8192` is just an example - OP can adjust this to whatever size they need for their strings. Finally, as I've mentioned in the comment, if OP is absolutely positive they'll never go multithreaded, `buffer` can be made `static` which eliminates any stack size limitations.

Comment: Good point, though that begs the question... here's the actual macro:

    #define AI_PRINT(outputType, severity, pBrain, msg, ...) \
    do { \
        char buffer[AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE]; \
        AI_PRINT_BUFFER(buffer, AI_OUTPUT_BUFFER_SIZE, outputType, severity, pBrain, msg, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    } while(__LINE__ == -1) \

With it wrapped in the do loop like that, I'd think I would get the same result (i.e. the buffer would only be created on the stack once).  I wonder if the compiler is optimizing that away, or if I already fixed this and didn't realize it...